# Prevent adding id to form elements in Spring tag library

Tags: html, spring, jstl

When I write:

```
<form:input path="fieldName">
```

it converts to

```
<input type="text" id="fieldName" path="fieldName">
```

How I can prevent Spring from adding `id` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Leaving `id` blank will cause spring not to display id attribute.

for example:

```
<form:input path="fiedlName" id="" />
```